# Winforms/C# faulty Cursor.Position.X or Y on a non-100% Windows scale

Tags: c#, winforms, scale, resolution, cursor-position

In a Winforms window using C#, when I retrieve `Cursor.Position.X` or `Cursor.Position.Y` on a Windows 10 system using 150% scale (1920x1080 resolution), I find that the bottom-right most pixel is 1279 by 719, when it should be 1919 by 1079.

This problem doesn't occur when the Windows "Scale and layout" figure (from Display settings) is set to 100%. It does however occur when not set to 100% (e.g: 150%).

I've tried setting the AutoScaleMode of the form to 'None', 'Dpi', and 'Font', but to no avail. I also don't want to fudge the solution by multiplying the retrieved figure by 1.5, since it'll be missing a few pixels due to quantization.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Setting `AutoScaleMode` does not affect Windows' detection of DPI-awareness. What version of WinForms and .NET are you using? Is your application DPI-aware at all?

Comment: I'm using .NET 4 client profile. Winforms version? That's a new on me. How do I find that one out? No idea if it's DPI-aware.

Comment: @Dai: Added the manifest file from this page to my project and it seems to have done the trick: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-   ........ Is it okay to completely overwrite the gubbins that VS initially had in the manifest file to begin with?

Comment: The auto generated manifest of VS already contains such a block enabling DPI awareness you simply have to uncomment.